# Create directshow filter object in expression encoder sdk

Tags: directshow, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I have a directshow filter that can be used by expression encoder.
Is it possible to create two objects of this filter using expression encoder sdk( two projects)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter will be instantiated each time applications need it, so there is nothing to prevent 2+ instances of your object, except possibly the case where application "keeps track" of devices in use and does not give you an option to use the same device again (the application might be under assumption that device is "real", not virtual, and cannot work simultaneously in two pipelines) and your workaround is to register 2+ virtual devices of the same type then.